# Log for URL on logcat Android Studio Bumblebee has showed but replaced with star

Tags: java, android

I just update Android Studio an Gradle with latest version. But I have problem when i print log for URL on logcat, path URL has showed but replaced with star like this

[image]

sample my code

```
 Log.d("URL " + TAG, URL);
```

So how to show full path? thanks for advice